# What does [u'abcd', u'bcde'] mean in Python?

Tags: python, append

Used a loop to add a bunch of elements to a list with
mylist = []

```
for x in otherlist:
mylist.append(x[0:5])
```

But instead of the expected result ['x1','x2',...], I got: [u'x1', u'x2',...]. Where did the u's come from and why? Also is there a better way to loop through the other list, inserting the first six characters of each element into a new list?

Comment: first 5 or first 6?  [0:5] is only 5 characters

Comment: Please ask one question at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The u means unicode, you probably will not need to worry about it

```
mylist.extend(x[:5] for x in otherlist)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `u` means *unicode*. It's Python's internal string representation (from version ... ?).

Most times you don't need to worry about it. (Until you do.)

Answer (score 1):

The answers above me already answered the "u" part - that the string is encoded in Unicode. About whether there's a better way to extract the first 6 letters from the items in a list:

```
>>> a = ["abcdefgh", "012345678"]
>>> b = map(lambda n: n[0:5], a);
>>> for x in b:
    print(x)

abcde
01234
```

So, `map` applies a function (`lambda n: n[0:5]`) to each element of `a` and returns a new list with the results of the function for every element. More precisely, in Python 3, it returns an iterator, so the function gets called only as many times as needed (i.e. if your list has 5000 items, but you only pull 10 from the result `b`, `lambda n: n[0:5]` gets called only 10 times). In Python2, you need to use `itertools.imap` instead.

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3]
>>> def plusone(x):
    print("called with {}".format(x))
    return x + 1

>>> b = map(plusone, a)
>>> print("first item: {}".format(b.__next__()))
called with 1
first item: 2
```

Of course, you can apply the function "eagerly" to every element by calling `list(b)`, which will give you a normal list with the function applied to each element on creation.

```
>>> b = map(plusone, a)
>>> list(b)
called with 1
called with 2
called with 3
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: I'm not seeing how this answers the question. Could you explain the code a bit?

Comment: I agree, I'll extend the answer ASAP.

Comment: map returns a list, not an iterator.  Its not lazy

Comment: @cmd thank you for the warning, I'm not using Python 2 so I wasn't aware that it wasn't lazy there... Anyways, I'm glad they fixed it in 3 :)